# Nginx serve user directories and web root at the same time

Tags: webserver, nginx

I want to serve directories from each users home directory; like `example.com/~user` which will be served from `/home/user/www`. There are some examples around there (like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126745/set-up-nginx-to-serve-files-from-subdirectories); which partially works for me.

My issue is: If I could enable user directories, the root (examle.com/) gives 404 not found. Both root directory and user directories cannot be enabled at the same time.

Probably I'm messing up the configuration. Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`. I've tried putting the "user dir" block above and below the "root" location; but the result is the same.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #[trimmed]...

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}


server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #[trimmed]...

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot

    #root
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    #user dir
    location ~ ^/(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
        alias /home/$1/www$2;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        autoindex on;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    #[trimmed]...

}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Could anyone help me serving the web root directory and user directories at the same time?

Comment: You seem to be missing a `~` in your regular expression. Try: `location ~ ^/~([^/]+)(/.*)?$ { ... }`

Comment: Oh, works! But why? Without the missing `~` , I should have been able to access `example.com/user` (not `example.com/~user`), haven't I? But I was not able to do so.

Comment: Yes, but then web root would not work.

Comment: Thank you, would you like to post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it as the solution?